# Implementation of active appearance models

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having an internship in the field of computer vision, and i am really interested to know some details about the implementation of the Active Appearence Models [aam-opencv](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/) that exists in the `Google Code` site.
In fact, i downloaded [aam-opencv.tar.gz](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/downloads/detail?name=aam-opencv.tar.gz) then built it with cmake and i solved some syntax problems but the only error that i am still having when i try to generate the solution is the following :

This function should return something:

```
  aamImage* delaunay:: warpImageToMeanShape(aamImage*input)
     {
      }
```

I wonder if there is something missing in that function, or is it a compiler problem.

Please give me an answer or just guide me to complete the missing part of that function.
I would really appreciate if anyone kindly help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is not used in code function, so it is not important what it return. Some C++ compilers allow to write such code and give only warning, another treat as errors:

```
ReturnType f()
{
}
```

looks like you use not the same compiler as author of source code. So just add something like:

```
aamImage* delaunay:: warpImageToMeanShape(aamImage*input)
 {
     return NULL;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i added the line that you have suggested but now i'm having a huge number of the following link errors in the .obj files (unresolved external symbol) : error LNK1120, error LNK2001, error LNK 2019.